# search a given word into a letter puzzle diagonally

Tags: java, tostring

I have a two-dimensional array filled with random letters. I have words to find in that array.

I have written a `toString` method that uses:

- `startX` : The start X position of the String to be found
- `startY` : The start Y position of the String to be found
- `endX` : The end X position of the String to be found
- `endY` : The end Y position of the String to be found

The code that I provide works horizontally and vertically but does not work for diagonals. How can I print words which are placed in the array diagonally?

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (startX == endX) {
        if (startY < endY) {
            for (int i = startY; i <= endY; i++)
                sb.append(i).append("x").append(startY).append("  ");
        } else {
            for (int i = endY; i <= startY; i++)
                sb.append(i).append("x").append(startY).append("  ");
        }
    }
    if (startY == endY) {
        if (startX < endX) {
            for (int i = startX; i <= endX; i++)
                sb.append(i).append("x").append(startY).append("  ");
        } else
            for (int i = endX; i <= startX; i++)
                sb.append(i).append("x").append(startY).append("  ");
    }
    if (startX > endX && startY > endY) {
        int i = startX;
        int j = startY;
        while (i >= endX)
            sb.append(i--).append("x").append(j--).append("  ");
    } else if (startX > endX && startY < endY) {
        int i = startX;
        int j = startY;
        while (i >= endX)
            sb.append(i--).append("x").append(j++).append("  ");
    } else if (startX < endX && startY > endY) {
        int i = startX;
        int j = startY;
        while (i >= endX)
            sb.append(i++).append("x").append(j--).append("  ");
    } else if (startX < endX && startY < endY) {
        int i = startX;
        int j = startY;
        while (i >= endX)
            sb.append(i++).append("x").append(j++).append("  ");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do, please formulate your question more clearly.

Comment: I have a puzzle with random letters and i need to find some words in that puzzle.

Comment: For me it is not clear either. If you have a letter puzzle and you are looking for specific words inside the puzzle I would suggest a total different approach. Is that what are you looking for?

Comment: Yes random letter puzzle. There are random letters in 2 dims. array and i'm looking for some words in it. The words may be placed horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

Comment: In that case I suggest you to reformulate the question by asking the code needed to search a given word into a letter puzzle. As a possible solution, I would construct a 2D array with the letters and look for the first letter of the word. When found, try to match the letters of all the available directions with the rest of the letters of the word. It may not be the best solution in terms of performance but it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that what you are looking for is a way to find a word in a letter puzzle.

In such a case, I suggest you to store the puzzle on a 2D array and the word to find in a String. Then you need to check all the positions of the array that have the same character than the begining character of the String you are looking for (in the code I provide: `findWord`). Once you find a match, you need to check the rest of the characters of the string (in the code I provide: `checkDirections`). If the rest of the characters match then you have found the string, otherwise you need to check for the other directions or for the next appearance of the first letter of the string.

Next I provide the code:

```
package letterPuzzle;

import java.util.Random;


public class LetterPuzzle {

private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
private static final int[] DIRECTIONS_X = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1 };
private static final int[] DIRECTIONS_Y = new int[] { 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1 };

private static int N;
private static char[][] puzzle;


private static void initializePuzzle() {
    Random r = new Random();
    puzzle = new char[N][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            puzzle[i][j] = ALPHABET.charAt(r.nextInt(ALPHABET.length()));
        }
    }

    // Add the JAVA word in a location
    if (N < 6) {
        System.out.println("[ERRRO] Example needs N >= 6");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    puzzle[2][3] = 'j';
    puzzle[3][3] = 'a';
    puzzle[4][3] = 'v';
    puzzle[5][3] = 'a';
}

private static void printPuzzle() {
    System.out.println("[DEBUG] Puzzle");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            System.out.print(puzzle[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("[DEBUG] End Puzzle");
}

private static boolean findWord(String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            // We check all the matrix but only try to match the word if the first letter matches
            if (puzzle[i][j] == word.charAt(0)) {
                if (checkDirections(i, j, word)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private static boolean checkDirections(int initX, int initY, String word) {
    System.out.println("Searching " + word + " from (" + initX + ", " + initY + ")");
    // Checks the different directions from (initX, initY) position
    for (int dirIndex = 0; dirIndex < DIRECTIONS_X.length; ++dirIndex) {
        System.out.println("  - Searching direction " + dirIndex);
        boolean wordMatches = true;
        // Checks all the characters in an specific direction
        for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < word.length() && wordMatches; ++charIndex) {
            int x = initX + DIRECTIONS_X[dirIndex] * charIndex;
            int y = initY + DIRECTIONS_Y[dirIndex] * charIndex;
            System.out.println("    -- Checking position (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= N || y >= N || puzzle[x][y] != word.charAt(charIndex)) {
                System.out.println("    -- Not match");
                wordMatches = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("    -- Partial match");
            }
        }

        // If the word matches we stop, otherwise we check other directions
        if (wordMatches) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Check args
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("[ERROR] Invalid usage");
        System.err.println("[ERROR] main <puzzleSize> <wordToSearch>");
    }

    // Get args
    N = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
    String word = args[1];

    // Initialize puzzle (randomly)
    initializePuzzle();
    printPuzzle();

    // Search word
    boolean isPresent = findWord(word);
    if (isPresent) {
        System.out.println("Word found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Word NOT found");
    }
}

}
```

Notice that:

- The puzzle matrix is randomly initialized and I hardcoded the word 'java' on the 2,3 -> 5,3 positions (this is just for the example but you should initialize the puzzle from the command line or from a file).
- The ALPHABET variable is used only for the random generation.
- The directions are stored on two 1D arrays to make the 8 directions programatically but you can unroll for the sake of clarity.
- It is probably not best efficient code in terms of performance since you will double check lots of positions if the first character of the string appears several times. However it is still a feasible and easy solution.

Comment: I changed my toString method for print every letter's location.(I changed my question completely). My new method works horizontally and vertically but not for diagonally. Because of my project i need to do like this method. Thanks for your great help but can you look my new method?

Comment: The code that you provide is not really looking for a string anywhere. I mean, you are storing on a StringBuilder things of the form 1x2 2x3 3x3. Is that what are you looking for? A way to print a diagonal 1x2 2x3... from start up to end?

Comment: yes it's that i'm looking for. And found the solution looking at your code. Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh nice. You should post your own answer and accept that one so others can learn from it :)

Answer (score 0):

If :

1. each word of yours is in a particular row and doesn't overflows to next row and
2. all words are consecutive

then you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

    for(int c = startY; c<=endY; c++) {
        string.append(startX).append("x").append(c).append(", ");
    }

    return string.toString();
}
```

Comment: Actually it worked but some words going backwards. For example: C A I R E G L A N G T N N I  (ALGERIA). Backward ones not worked.